# Is there a way to identify bus lines serving a particular city?

Tags: buses

When I am aware of another company, I have always found it less expensive than Greyhound.  But with a zillion companies running buses, it's not practical to search one by one to see if they serve the place I am going to/from.

We have lots of search engines that aggregate all airlines, and even if we didn't, it's not hard to get a list of airlines for a particular airport.

But is there a service similar to either for buses?

Comment: @nic Where did the OP mention USA?

Comment: @Berwyn: In the first comment to the accepted answer: "Fort Smith, AR". Feel free to revert if you believe my assumption is too far-fetched. Cheers!

Comment: @nic I doubt the OP only wants to go to Fort Smith

Comment: Berwyn is correct.  In fact, my next destination is Indianapolis, and after that  a town thirty kilometers from Fort Smith with no official bus service.  But I wander a lot and when I don't have to cross an ocean and am not in a hurry, I prefer bus or train.  (Being retired, I am almost never in a hurry.)

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, because there is no IATA or ICAO for buses, so a worldwide answer is unlikely to exist and answer would have to be provided for every location in the world.

Comment: Well, is there an international organization for bikeshares?  Yet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bicycle-sharing_systems exists.  And at least one answer here makes a good start.  Would you prefer I had asked nine nearly identical questions?  That's how many countries where I've used buses in the past three years.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Busbud](https://www.busbud.com/en) is a service that aggregates many intercity bus lines. [One of their employees](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/20576/carl-from-busbud) is a travel.stackexchange member, so you can contact him if you have any questions about the site.

Google Maps transit directions is good for shorter-distance commuter buses in many parts of the world.

[Rome2rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/) is not focused but often has bus options for any given city pair.

In addition, Wikitravel and Wikivoyage usually list transportation options for cities, including intercity bus services. You may find options there not listed on an aggregator.

Comment: I hope there's more than this, but it's better than the nothing I had when I posted.  :-). BusBud doesn't know Fort Smith, AR (at least two lines go there).  Google Maps only knows Greyhound.  WikiVoyage and WikiTravel...well, at least one of them is pasting text from the other.

Comment: @WGroleau There may well be other options too. My answer was a set of suggestions of things I was aware of, not a comprehensive list of resources. But thanks for accepting it!

Comment: I didn't mean to sound ungrateful.  It's infinitely better than nothing at all, though it's not quite what I hoped for.  :-)

Comment: I added Rome2rio. At least worth mentioning. But it doesn't warrant a separate answer.

Comment: I do use Rome2Rio a lot, but it will typically list one to three bus options, even for routes where I know there are many.  Thanks--you're right, it is worth mentioning.